# Drag and Drop Component on Top of Background Image

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, drag-and-drop

I have an application that involves a background image which fills the frame, and then a number of JLabels being dragged around on top of the image. I was having trouble getting the background image to redraw continuously and correctly when labels were dragged (a trail was created behind labels), I placed the background image in a JPanel, and then put a transparent JPanel on top to use for dragging and dropping JLabels. However, my JLabels do not appear. How can I modify my code to allow for labels to be dragged on top of a background image?

The main class:

```
public class InteractionBlocks {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BlocksFrame frame = new BlocksFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(1000, 650); //full size is 8000, 5000
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

The BlocksFrame class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BlocksFrame extends JFrame implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    private JPanel panel = new JPanel(null);
    private BackgroundPanel backgroundPanel = new BackgroundPanel(null);
    private boolean drag = false;

    //Block is a JLabel with additional information stored
    private Block qa = new Block(Pattern.QUESTION_ANSWER, Actor.HUMAN);

    public BlocksFrame() {
        this.add(backgroundPanel);
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        backgroundPanel.add(panel);

        addButtons();
    }

    private void addButtons() {     
        panel.add(qa);
        qa.setBounds(100, 50, qa.getIcon().getIconWidth(), qa.getIcon().getIconHeight());
        qa.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        qa.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        if (drag == true) {
            JComponent jc = (JComponent) e.getSource();
            jc.setLocation(jc.getX() + e.getX(), jc.getY() + e.getY());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {        
        drag = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        ((Block) e.getSource()).setLocation(((Block) e.getSource()).getX(), 300);

        drag = false;
    }

    //additional @Override methods that are empty
}
```

The BackgroundPanel class:

```
public class BackgroundPanel extends JPanel {

    public BackgroundPanel(LayoutManager mngr) {
        super(mngr);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        ImageIcon background = new ImageIcon("./figures/ui_new.png");
        g.drawImage(background.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, don't override paint. Basically what you are doing is painting over the containers contents.  Instead, use paintComponent

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    ImageIcon background = new ImageIcon("./figures/ui_new.png");
    g.drawImage(background.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
}
```

Your "panel" is also not transparent, try using...

```
panel.setOpaque(false);
```

**Additional**

Because you are using a `null` layout on both the background pane and "overlay" pane, the overlay pane has no size or position, making it effectively invisible.

Now, you could use a `BorderLayout` on the background pane or simply avoid using the "overlay" pane, as I'm not really seeing any benefit for it at this time.

Comment: I appreciate both of these suggestions - missed that my panel was not opaque. However, the JLabel still does not appear. Any additional suggestions?

Comment: Don't add the mouseListener to the `Block` component, try adding to the "drag" panel instead, the points will make better sense...

Comment: Sorry, don't mean to be stream of consciousness, but if I remove the second, transparent "panel" and then add buttons directly to the BackgroundPanel, it all seems to work. Are there any disadvantages to this approach?

Comment: Because you're using a `null` layout, `panel` has no size or location, therefore it won't "appear"